# Visual Studio - Could not find type

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Opening a example project. When I try to open the main form I get 6 errors. The main two say that VS could not find a type. I can see the file that defines the type in the tree but the file does not have a c# icon. Here is the icon of the file in question:

[image]

Why is VS not recognizing these c# files? How do I resolve this?

I have tried excluding from project and then including but that did not solve.

Comment: There is obviously something happening here. I have a sub-classed control which was working for about two months, and all of a sudden I'm getting this error and it's complaining about said sub-class...

Answer (score 0):

Right click the file, select "Include in Project".  Then go to Properties, and make sure the Build Action is set to "Compile".

Comment: The files are included and set to compile. I have also excluded the affected files and the included them. I have toggled "compile" to something else and back. No help. When i double click on the files then design view opens but there is nothing there except text saying I can edit the code. When i edit code I see the code and it looks fine. What is the icon with the three tiny boxes in the lower lh corner?